# What site would I use for talking about apps, how software works, why and how?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about why apps are updated and require specific versions of OS where would I ask this>

Comment: I can't think of any SE website where a question like that would be on topic

Comment: So what should I do?, is there a site the would have a general topic like this?

Comment: As I said, I cannot think of a SE website where your question as it's currently described, would be on topic.

Comment: The reason you're getting “none” as an answer is that you seem to want to ask a question to start a discussion, rather than to ask a specific question that has a specific answer. And although there *could* be a specific question distilled out of the discussion topic you've described, it would not be very informative – you would need to ask *many* basic questions to start getting a clear understanding of the knowledge you're missing on this subject. Suggestion: read books on how operating systems (OSes) and software work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no site on the Stack Exchange network where you can ask such a question. The reason for this: it is a discussion-type question rather than an fixed question that addresses a specific problem and can be answered in a single answer.

Here is the rule for posting on the Stack Overflow site (and correct me if I am wrong, but this applies to all sites part of the Stack Exchange network):

> *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.* - [**Stack Overflow - Help Center**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)